# CoInitializeEx и проблема с PeekMessage

Tags: c++, winapi, com

В документации `WinAPI` к функции `PeekMessageW` сказано:

> A handle to the window whose messages are to be retrieved. The window
>   must belong to the current thread.

Хорошо, я попробовал установить одно-поточный режим:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FIX_USE(argc)
    FIX_USE(argv)

    const HRESULT result = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    if(!SUCCEEDED(result))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize single thread apartment..." << std::endl;
        return 0x1;
    }

    try
    {
        window window(L"Window");
        window.show();
        window.set_client_size(size(1280, 720));
        MSG msg = {};

        while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
        {
            if(PeekMessageW(&msg, window.get_handle(), 0u, 0u, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessageW(&msg);
            }
            // TODO: update and render methods call here
        }

        CoUninitialize();
        return 0x0;
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 0x2;
    }
}
```

Так же в разделе ремарк сказано:

> Note that PeekMessage always retrieves WM_QUIT messages, no matter
>   which values you specify for wMsgFilterMin and wMsgFilterMax.

Но это не так! Сообщение `WM_QUIT` никогда не будет получено.

В то время, как в процедуре окна:

```
LRESULT window::window_procedure(HWND h_wnd, UINT msg, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_SIZE:
        on_size_changed(size(LOWORD(l_param), HIWORD(l_param)));
        break;
    default: return DefWindowProcW(h_wnd, msg, w_param, l_param);
    }

    return LRESULT(FALSE);
}
```

А последним извлеченным сообщением является: `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`.

В чем может быть проблема получения этого сообщения, или я не правильно установил одно-поточный режим? Или окно находится не в этом потоке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PeekMessageW` работает только с окнами, созданными в данном потоке, `CoInitializeEx` вообще не имеет к ней отношения. `PostQuitMessage` отправляет сообщение в очередь сообщения потока, а не конкретному окну. А указывая `window.get_handle()` будут изыматься только сообщения, адресованные этому окну и его дочерним окнам.